# Type hinting: Check if types are compatible

Tags: python, python-3.9

I'm using type annotatiots to do some basic type checking and automated type conversions.

As part of that, I'm looking to check if a given type should be assignable to some field of a data class, i.e. if the type is "compatible" with the type annotation on my data class.

Is there any out-of-the-box way to check if a given type is assignable to some other type? I.e.

```
from typing import Optional, Union, Annotated, Type

def is_assignable(from_what: Type, to_what: Type) -> bool:
  // .. how?

is_assignable(int, int) // should be true
is_assignable(int, Optional[int]) should be true
is_assignable(int, Annotated[Union[str, Optional[int]], "hello world"]) // should be true
is_assignable(float, Annotated[Union[str, Optional[int]], "hello world"]) // False. Can't assign float to Annotated[Union[str, Optional[int]], "hello world"])
```

I could try unwrapping all the typing.* logic myself, i.e. unwrap Optional, Union, Annotated, and so forth, but that feels rather ugly (and not too maintainable, if new stuff is added in more recent python versions).

Comment: Why not just using [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)?

Comment: @maxi.marufo Because I'm not primarily using this to do static type checking, but also e.g. dynamic type conversion. Example: Input is some dataframe that has a pandas.TimeStamp column, but dataclass with matching property name expects a datetime.datetime, then I'm doing the conversion under the hood

Comment: Should it be super generic? or will only get builtins for the `from_what` parameter? In other words - would you want to support this call? `is_assignable(Annotated[Union[str], Optional[int]], Optional[int])` - what would that return? what would your last example return if we switch the `float` with `int` and the `int` with `float`? (do you consider that every float can be an "integer" as well?)

Comment: I have found https://pypi.org/project/typing-utils/#issubtype from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68934308/check-parameter-types-dynamically-in-python-and-typings . Maybe this question should be considered a duplicate. However that library hasn't been maintained in a while.

Comment: @no_hex Ideally, yes, should be super generic. Regarding implicit conversions? Personally I don't care. Perhaps Bogey does

Comment: Another library I found: https://github.com/erezsh/runtype

Answer (score 1):

Using pydantic models instead of dataclasses is a way to get this out of the box, for example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: str

try:
    x = MyModel(a=2, b="asd")  # OK
except ValidationError as exc:
    ....  # Catch the error if any, in this case this block will not execute

try:
    x = MyModel(a="asd", b=2)  # Wrong types, cannot parse "asd" to int
except ValidationError as exc:
    ....  # Catch the error and work around it.
```

Note that types are not strictly enforced, Pydantic is actually a parsing library and not a validation library (although the words validation, validator, etc, are everywhere, in fact the meaning is of parsing). Therefore, `MyModel(a=2, b=3)` will also work because `3` can be parsed to a string `str(3) -> "3"`, but you can implement your own more strict validators if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my fault. Now it's working as you expected, for me.

```
from typing import Optional, Union, Annotated, Type, get_origin, get_args

def is_assignable(from_what: Type, to_what: Type) -> bool:
    # Unwrap Annotated type if present
    if get_origin(to_what) is Annotated:
        to_what = get_args(to_what)[0]

    return issubclass(from_what, to_what)

is_assignable(int, int)  # True
is_assignable(int, Optional[int])  # True
is_assignable(int, Annotated[Union[str, Optional[int]], "hello world"])  # True
is_assignable(float, Annotated[Union[str, Optional[int]], "hello world"])  # False
```

Comment: ^This will fail in the case of `MyModel(a: int, b: str)` >> the following should succeed: `MyModel("1", "2")` since `"1"` can be coerced to an int. What about `MyModel(1, 2)` >> `2` can be coerced to a string as well.

Comment: Similarly, fails with `is_assignable(int, Literal["1"])`