# Check parameter types dynamically in python and typings

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a class with a sort of pipeline structure and I'd like to have a function that checks that the steps in the pipeline are compatible. Thus I want to loop through all steps and check that the input is compatible with the output of the previous step given the type hints. Now, this is done by extracting the types from the signatures and then comparing the types. The problem is, how do I compare the types? Seems I can't find any way of doing it for some reason. For instance `Any` can't be used at all with `issubclass`. I use python 3.8. I would like for it to work for instances such as:

```
is_compatible(List, Any) # => True
is_compatible(List[np.ndarray], List[Union[np.ndarray, list]]) # => True
is_compatible(List[str], List[int]) # => False
# etc.
```

Comment: please provide a desired input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can try a 3rd-party library `typing-utils`.
- https://github.com/bojiang/typing_utils
- https://pypi.org/project/typing-utils/

#### example

```
    from typing_utils import issubtype
    issubtype(typing.List, typing.Any) == True
    issubtype(list, list) == True
    issubtype(list, typing.List) == True
    issubtype(list, typing.List[int]) == False
```